# Изобразить на комплексной плоскости множество точек удовлетворяющих условию

Tags: математика

[image]

Прошу помощи в решении. Положил z = x + yi. Re(z-i) будет x. Таким образом получаю уравнение вида |z+i|> 1-x. Раскрывая модуль и возвел в квадрат. Получил x^2 + y^2+2y+1 > 1-2x+x^2. Сократил и получил y^2+2y > -2x. Как решать дальше чтобы изобразить множество точек на плоскости. Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно где то допустил ошибку

Comment: Еще надо, например, сообразить, что при `x>1` правая часть отрицательна, так что вся полуплоскость тоже годится... Если внимательно посмотреть при возведении в квадрат, то аналогично получается, что годится `x>1/2`. Дальше поверните картинку на 90 градусов и постройте параболу :)

Comment: Или запихать в [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Sqrt%5BPower%5Bx%2C2%5D%2BPower%5B%5C%2840%29y%2B1%5C%2841%29%2C2%5D%5D%3E1-x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если это делать руками, то надо аккуратно преобразовывать неравенство, рассматривать все случаи, чтобы не потерять (или не приобрести) лишние решения... Что-то типа такого.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]